# How to get all HTML tags that contains specific string in their attribute values using Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am working on getting all HTML tags that contains specific string in thier attribute values in the below code

```
<meta name="DCSext.oo_market" content="en-us">
<a href="http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/" title="Find help for Word">
<a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/microsoft-account-help#microsoft-account=tab1" title="Microsoft Account">
```

I want all the tags which contains "en-us" in their attribute means my output should return all the above html tags. Could
anyone please help me how to get it using HTML Agility Pack?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have done below things but nothing got worked for me
1) var contentNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(*,'en-us')]");
2) var contentNode1 = from node in doc.DocumentNode.Attributes.ToList() where node.ToString().Contains("en-us") select node;
3)var contentNode2 = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("en-us"));

Comment: meta tag also should be selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following XPath `//*[@*[contains(., 'en-us')]]` which selects any elements which have any attribute which contains string `en-us`:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_html_file);    
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(., 'en-us')]]");
```

Or LINQ way:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
               .Where(n => n.Attributes.Any(a => a.Value.Contains("en-us")));
```